# Windows phone get photo in chunks

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7

i want to upload a photo in a background task, the limitation is maximum 5mb ram usage.

How can i get the picture in binary chunks?

Is it possible in a HTTPWebRequest write data in chunks?

Answer (score 1):

Try using [http range headers](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.35).

They let you grab the entity in small parts.